# jQuery Loop with cumulative logic?

Tags: jquery

How do you loop through the results from a children() or each() call in jQuery when you want to work with some cumulative result?  For example sum up numbers in checkboxes and change a class if they get over 100%.  All the example seem to only perform logic that is independent for each iteration.

I'm looking for the javascript/jquery equiv of this c#

```
var x = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine(x.All(y => y > 0));
```

This is what I have now, but it seems like there should be something cleaner.

```
var count = 0;
$(this).parent().children().each(
    function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
);

if ($(this).parent().children().length == count) {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("selected");
}
else {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: Example html? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the obvious iterate and sum approach, you can use the newer javascript iteration functions. Assuming you want so sum some numbers:

```
var sum = objects
    //convert to jquery selection of numbers
    .map(function() {return +$(this).val(); })
    //convert to javascript array
    .get() 
    //add together
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
```

---

For your example:

```
var checkboxes = $(this).parent().children()
var allSelected = checkboxes.map(function () {
    return $(this).hasClass("selected");
}).get().every(function(x) { return x; });
```

You can go one stage better by extending jQuery

```
$.fn.every = function(f) {
    return [].every.call(this, function(x) {
        return f.call(x);
    });
}
```

Leaving you with:

```
var checkboxes = $(this).parent().children()
var allSelected = checkboxes.every(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I was having problems articulating.  How to implement the equivalent of the IEnumerable extension methods so you don't have to iterate and sum.  Thanks

Comment: A lot of said methods already exist on native javascript arrays.

Comment: @Eric Please could you give me some info about the `+$(this)` bit and the functions you used? Never knew about that... awesome, do you have some useful links? How is it cross-browser compatible? I'd appreciate so much any info. (Anyway I'll google around...)

Comment: @Cranio: It's not `+$(this)`. You've parsed it incorrectly. It's `+$(this).val()` aka `+( $(this).val() )`. Simply put unary `+` will try and convert its datatype to a number.

Comment: Yes, sorry, @Eric, you're right. So, it's basically like I do in PHP when I convert its non-strongly typed variables in numbers by doing `$var2 = $var1 + 0`, right?

Comment: In other words, you map the array with *JQuery*'s `map()` by extrapolating the values as properties into numbers, convert the collection into a *Javascript* object with `get()` and use the `reduce()` function (which I didn't know) to collapse all into a total, right? So clever.

Comment: @Cranio: exactly. You could do the `get`/`map` the other way around with some small changes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Javascript/Jquery are not SQL, there is no defined concept of "cumulative"/groupwise operations. Also, "cumulative logic" is a rather vague term, it really depends on the particular task you want to perform.

So, your sum example can be adapted for `each()` with the help of an external variable, for `input`/text tags it would be:

```
var sum = 0;
var objects = $("input.myclass");
objects.each(function() {sum+=Number($(this).val());});
if (sum>100) objects.addClass("anotherclass");
```

For checkboxes: I'm not sure what you mean by "sum numbers in checkboxes", do you mean the values?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the linear array operations [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and `filter`, jQuery doesn't have a polyfill for it, but I think what you're looking for is [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It is well-supported in newer browsers.

You can implement the javascript you have there using the boolean toggleClass syntax.

```
var count = $(this).parent().children(".selected").length;
$(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("selected",
    $(this).parent().children().length === count);
```

Comment: This looks quite elegant as well!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard. I'm not sure if this will work 100%, but it'll show you how to do cumulative logic

```
var score = 0;
$("#checkboxDivId input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function()
{
    score += $(this).val();
});
if(score >= 100)
{
    //Put your code here
}
```

Obviously this would only work if your score is the value property of the checkbox, and if the selector is correct (not 100% sure on whether or not the selector is correct)